# mysql select relation two items

Tags: php, mysql, tags, relation

Categories

```
id -- PK
pid -- FK to self (id), allow NULL
name
description
slug
```

Tags

```
id -- PK
name
description
slug
```

Cat_Rel

```
id -- PK
pid -- FK: Post Id
cid -- FK: Category Id
```

Tag_Rel

```
id -- PK
pid -- FK: Post Id
tid -- FK: Tag Id
```

I need this result in one query:
row : pid | tag1,tag2,tag3 | cat1,cat5

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with two subqueries and `union all`:

```
select pid, max(tags), max(cats)
from ((select t.pid, group_concat(t.name) as tags, NULL as cats
       from tag_rel tr join
            tags t
            on tr.tid = .tid
       group by t.pid
      ) union all
      (select c.pid, NULL, group_concat(c.name) as cats
       from cat_rel cr join
            cats c
            on cr.cid = c.id
      )
     ) ct
group by pid;
```

This will ensure that you get all posts, even those with no tags and/or no categories.